# Spring Data Cassandra Not handling raw UDTS, throws no suitable converter exception

Tags: spring, cassandra, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

After upgrading to Spring 2.4.0 , spring data Cassandra is throwing no suitable converter found exception

Here is my UDT

```
@Setter
@Getter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@UserDefinedType(value="ADDRESS")
@AllArgsConstructor

public class Address implements Serializable{
    
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String address1;
    private String address2;
    private String state;
    private String city;
    private String country;
    private String zip;
    private String longitude;
    private String latitude;
    
}
```

Here is my main table

```
package com.sellingsimplified.msor.common.schema;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.CassandraType;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.CassandraType.Name;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.Column;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.PrimaryKey;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.Table;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Field;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.FieldType;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Table(value = "#{@contactCassandra}")
@Document(indexName = "#{@contactIndex}")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Contact implements Serializable,MSOREntity {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5141439096729821675L;
    @PrimaryKey
    @Id
    private Long contactid;// 1
    private Long companyid;// 1
    @CassandraType(type =Name.UDT, userTypeName = "NAME")
    @Field(type = FieldType.Auto, includeInParent = true)
    private com.sellingsimplified.msor.common.schema.Name contactname;// 1
    
    @javax.validation.constraints.Email
    private String corpemail;// 1
    @CassandraType(type = Name.UDT, userTypeName = "EMAIL")
    @Field(type = FieldType.Auto, includeInParent = true)
    private Email contactemail;// 1
    
    @NotEmpty(message="Jobtitle cannot be empty")
    private String jobtitle;
    private String skill;// newly added field
    @CassandraType(type =Name.UDT, userTypeName = "ADDRESS")
    @Field(type = FieldType.Auto, includeInParent = true)
    @Column("contactaddress")
    private Address contactaddress;
    @CassandraType(type = Name.UDT, userTypeName = "PHONE")
    @Field(type = FieldType.Auto, includeInParent = true)
    private Phone contactphone;
    private String companyname;
    /**
     * linkedinurl, facebookurl, twitterurl, xing_url, viadeo_url, misc_url
     */
    private Map<String, String> contactsocialurl;
    private String twitterhandle;
    private String jobfunction;
    private String createdby;
    private String modifiedby;
    private Date createdon;
    private Date modifiedon;
    private String updatedby;
    private Date updatedon;

    private String status;
    private String contactverificationstatus;
    private String copyaddress;
    private String contactverified;
    private String emailverified;
    private String phonenumberverified;
    private String senioritylevel;
    private String contactsource;
    private String lastmodifiedsystem;
    private String domain;
    private String comment;
    private String processstatus;
    private String enrichmentstage;
    private String thresholdstatus;
    private String incomingemailtype;
    private String pageaccessedby;
    private String groupid;


    private String emailpattern;
    private String emailcheck;
    private String websitedomain;
    private String humanhelp;
    
    private String notVerifiedreason;
    private String notVerifiedcomment;
    private String zone;
    private String companycheck;
    
    private String industry;
    private String employeetotal;

    @CassandraType(type =Name.UDT, userTypeName = "NAME")
    @Field(type = FieldType.Object, includeInParent = true)
    private com.sellingsimplified.msor.common.schema.Name contactnamenl;
    private String jobtitlenl;
    @CassandraType(type = Name.UDT, userTypeName = "ADDRESS")
    @Field(type = FieldType.Auto, includeInParent = true)
    private Address contactaddressnl;

    private String contacthash;
    private String sourceurl;
    @CassandraType(type = Name.UDT, userTypeName = "COMPANY")
    @Field(type = FieldType.Auto, includeInParent = true)
    private Company contactcompany;
    private Long tokenid = -1L;

    // new fields
    private Map<String, String> customfields;
    private Map<String, String> flags;
    private Set<String> usertags;
    private Set<String> systemtags;

    private String user;
    private String chromeuser;
    private String experience;
    private String notes;
    @CassandraType(type = Name.UDT, userTypeName = "JobHistory")
    @Field(type = FieldType.Auto, includeInParent = true)
    private List<JobHistory> jobhistory;
    private List<EmailHistory> emailhistory;

    private String contactidtxt;
    private Date lastaccessedate;
    private Date ecmverifiedon;
    private Date verifiedon;
    private String isactive;
    private String isverified;
    private String isarchived;
    private String isdeleted;
    private Set<Long> mergedcontactids;
    private String emaildomain;

    private String contactotherfield1;
    private String contactotherfield2;
    private String contactotherfield3;
    private String contactotherfield4;
    private String contactotherfield5;
    private String contactotherfield6;
    private String contactotherfield7;
    private String contactotherfield8;
    private String contactotherfield9;
    private String contactotherfield10;
    
    private String  linkedinurl;
    private String  facebookurl;
    private String  twitterurl;
    private String  miscurl;
    private String  linkedinhandle;
    private String facebookhandle;

    private String xinghandle;
    private String viadeolinkhandle;
    
    private String srcemail;
    // new fields

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((contacthash == null) ? 0 : contacthash.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Contact other = (Contact) obj;
        if (contacthash == null) {
            if (other.contacthash != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!contacthash.equals(other.contacthash))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public EntityType entityType() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return EntityType.CONTACT;
    }

    @Override
    public String hash() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return contacthash;
    }

}
```

Address is a User Defined Type and used in Table contact.

I am extending AbstractCassandraConfiguration to create Cassandra configutaion

```
package com.sellingsimplified.msor.common.cassandra;

import java.time.Duration;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cassandra.CassandraProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cassandra.CqlSessionBuilderCustomizer;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cassandra.DriverConfigLoaderBuilderCustomizer;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnProperty;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.AbstractCassandraConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.CqlSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.SchemaAction;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.SessionBuilderConfigurer;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.config.EnableCassandraRepositories;

import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.CqlSessionBuilder;
import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.config.DefaultDriverOption;
import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.config.DriverConfigLoader;

@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "cassandra.enable", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = false)
@EnableCassandraRepositories(basePackages = "com.sellingsimplified.msor.common.repository")
public class CassandraConfig extends AbstractCassandraConfiguration {

    @Value("${cassandra.table.contact:CONTACT}")
    private String contactCassandra;
    @Value("${cassandra.table.company:COMPANY}")
    private String companyCassandra;

    @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.contact-points}")
    private String contactPoints;

    @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.port}")
    private int port;

    @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.keyspace}")
    private String keySpace;

    @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.password}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.schema-action}")
    private String schemaAction;

    @Value("${cassandra.table.contact.history:ContactHistory}")
    private String contactHistoryCassandra;

    @Value("${cassandra.table.company.history:CompanyHistory}")
    private String companyHistoryCassandra;

    @Override
    protected String getKeyspaceName() {
        return keySpace;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getContactPoints() {
        return contactPoints;
    }

    @Override
    protected int getPort() {
        return port;
    }

    @Override
    public SchemaAction getSchemaAction() {
        return SchemaAction.valueOf(schemaAction);
    }

    protected boolean getMetricsEnabled() {
        return false;
    }

    @Bean(name = "companyCassandra")
    public String companyCassandra() {
        return companyCassandra;
    }

    @Bean(name = "contactHistoryCassandra")
    public String contactHistoryCassandra() {
        return contactHistoryCassandra;
    }

    @Bean(name = "companyHistoryCassandra")
    public String companyHistoryCassandra() {
        return companyHistoryCassandra;
    }

    @Bean(name = "contactCassandra")
    public String contactCassandra() {
        return contactCassandra;
    }

    @Bean
    public CqlSessionBuilderCustomizer authCustomizer(CassandraProperties properties) {
        return (builder) -> builder.withAuthCredentials(properties.getUsername(), properties.getPassword());
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public CqlSessionFactoryBean cassandraSession() {
        CqlSessionFactoryBean cassandraSession = super.cassandraSession();// super session should be called only once
        cassandraSession.setUsername(username);
        cassandraSession.setPassword(password);
        cassandraSession.setLocalDatacenter("DC1");

        return cassandraSession;
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getEntityBasePackages() {
        return new String[] { "com.sellingsimplified" };
    }


    @Override
    protected SessionBuilderConfigurer getSessionBuilderConfigurer() {
        return new SessionBuilderConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public CqlSessionBuilder configure(CqlSessionBuilder cqlSessionBuilder) {
                return cqlSessionBuilder.withConfigLoader(DriverConfigLoader.programmaticBuilder()
                        .withDuration(DefaultDriverOption.REQUEST_TIMEOUT, Duration.ofMillis(15000))
                        .withDuration(DefaultDriverOption.CONTROL_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, Duration.ofSeconds(100))
                        .withBoolean(DefaultDriverOption.METADATA_SCHEMA_ENABLED, false)
                        .withDuration(DefaultDriverOption.METADATA_SCHEMA_REQUEST_TIMEOUT, Duration.ofSeconds(100))
                        .withDuration(DefaultDriverOption.CONTROL_CONNECTION_AGREEMENT_TIMEOUT, Duration.ofSeconds(100))
                        .withDuration(DefaultDriverOption.CONNECTION_INIT_QUERY_TIMEOUT, Duration.ofSeconds(100))
                        .withDuration(DefaultDriverOption.CONNECTION_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, Duration.ofSeconds(100)).build());
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    DriverConfigLoaderBuilderCustomizer cassandraDriverCustomizer() {
        return (builder) -> builder
                .withDuration(DefaultDriverOption.CONTROL_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, Duration.ofSeconds(100))
                .withBoolean(DefaultDriverOption.METADATA_SCHEMA_ENABLED, false)
                .withDuration(DefaultDriverOption.METADATA_SCHEMA_REQUEST_TIMEOUT, Duration.ofSeconds(100))
                .withDuration(DefaultDriverOption.CONTROL_CONNECTION_AGREEMENT_TIMEOUT, Duration.ofSeconds(100))
                .withDuration(DefaultDriverOption.CONNECTION_INIT_QUERY_TIMEOUT, Duration.ofSeconds(100))
                .withDuration(DefaultDriverOption.CONNECTION_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, Duration.ofSeconds(100));

    }

    
}
```

**I am getting below exception while saving Contact Object**

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.cassandra.CassandraUncategorizedException: No converter found capable of converting from type [com.sellingsimplified.msor.common.schema.Address] to type [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.data.UdtValue]; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [com.sellingsimplified.msor.common.schema.Address] to type [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.data.UdtValue]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.CassandraExceptionTranslator.translate(CassandraExceptionTranslator.java:160) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.CassandraExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(CassandraExceptionTranslator.java:72) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.CqlSessionFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(CqlSessionFactoryBean.java:646) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-tx-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242) ~[spring-tx-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152) ~[spring-tx-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy135.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.sellingsimplified.msor.marchingengine.consumer.MSORGatewayEndpoint.processLead(MSORGatewayEndpoint.java:70) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:171) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:120) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.invoke(HandlerAdapter.java:48) ~[spring-kafka-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:321) ~[spring-kafka-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.BatchMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invoke(BatchMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:170) ~[spring-kafka-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.BatchMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(BatchMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:162) ~[spring-kafka-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.BatchMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(BatchMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:58) ~[spring-kafka-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeBatchOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1744) [spring-kafka-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeBatchOnMessageWithRecordsOrList(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1735) [spring-kafka-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeBatchOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1693) [spring-kafka-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeBatchListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1622) [spring-kafka-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    ... 7 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [com.sellingsimplified.msor.common.schema.Address] to type [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.data.UdtValue]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:322) ~[spring-core-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:195) ~[spring-core-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:175) ~[spring-core-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ConvertingPropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(ConvertingPropertyAccessor.java:120) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ConvertingPropertyAccessor.getProperty(ConvertingPropertyAccessor.java:91) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.getWriteValue(MappingCassandraConverter.java:744) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.writeMapFromWrapper(MappingCassandraConverter.java:490) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.write(MappingCassandraConverter.java:456) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.StatementFactory.insert(StatementFactory.java:307) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.doInsert(CassandraTemplate.java:632) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.insert(CassandraTemplate.java:622) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.support.SimpleCassandraRepository.save(SimpleCassandraRepository.java:93) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:524) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:531) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:156) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:131) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy135.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Makarand Prabhu I'm also facing same issue, did you get solution for this?

Comment: @nilesh_101 Did you find a solution?

Comment: Yes @Arya I had to write two different custom converters for read and write purpose which implements Converter interface. And register these converters in customConversions() method in CassandraConfig class.

Comment: @nilesh_101 When creating the custom converter did you have to make the class abstract? can you please post an example of your converters and CassandraConfig?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement a class annotated with `@Entity` that is mapped to your UDT.

Have a look at the [Entities](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.9/manual/mapper/entities/) page of the Java driver docs for details. Cheers!

Comment: I think this is for direct use of java-driver 4.9 , not through spring data , any ways I have tried this as well with no success.